# How to populate indexableField based on IngestDocument in Elasticsearch using IngestPlugin

Tags: java, elasticsearch, plugins

I am writing IngestPlugin, which needs to populate a timestamp (multi-field) based on fields in IngestDocument. I have defined an index as follows

```
 {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
          }
        }
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
          }
        }
      },
      "field3": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "default_pipeline": "my_pipeline"
  }
}
```

I tried to set value for "title.timestamp" using processor like this

```
@Override
public IngestDocument execute(IngestDocument ingestDocument) throws Exception {
    ingestDocument.setFieldValue("field1.timestamp", "2020-07-27");
    
    return ingestDocument;
}
```

I got the following error while inserting a document

```
{

  "error" : {

    "root_cause" : [

      {

        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",

        "reason" : "cannot set [timestamp] with parent object of type [java.lang.String] as part of path [field1.timestamp]"

      }

    ],

    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",

    "reason" : "cannot set [timestamp] with parent object of type [java.lang.String] as part of path [field1.timestamp]"

  },

  "status" : 400

}
```

Is there any way to populate multi-field (field1.timestamp) value on indesting document using Elasticsearch plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot populate a sub-field of a multi-field directly.

Since `field1` is of type `text`, you can only set `"field1": "2020-07-27"` and you'll get:

- the analyzed `text` value of `"2020-07-27"` in `field1` and
- the `date` value of `"2020-07-27"` in `field1.timestamp`

So you need to simply do this instead:

```
ingestDocument.setFieldValue("field1", "2020-07-27");
                                    ^
                                    |
                          remove .timestamp here
```

Comment: Can you provide some feedback about what didn't worked for you in my answer so we can sort it out?

Comment: Actually, I want to ingest a timestamp value not "field1" value

Comment: Then you need to create a separate field for the timestamp, not a sub-field. Can you explain why you created your mapping like that?